# maximum intersections between circles and lines

Tags: combinatorics

How do I go about systematically finding the maximum number of intersections between n lines and k circles? I don't wish to draw it out. For example if there are 2 circles and 3 lines then the maximum number of intersections is 17.

Comment: Any stright line have at most two intersections with a circle, so why 17 ?

Comment: Maximum number of intersections so add the intersections of circles with circles and lines with lines too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we have $k$ circles and $n$ lines, the answer is $2{k\choose2}+{n\choose2}+2nk$, since every two circles intersect at most at two points, every two lines at most one point and every line and circle at most two.

Comment: what about $n=1$ or $k=1$?

Comment: $2{k\choose2}=2{1\choose2}=0$ and ${n\choose2}={1\choose2}=0$, so the answer $2{k\choose2}+{n\choose2}+2nk=2$ as it is expected.